# Is it possible to change storyboard language at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, localization, storyboard, bundle

I'm using storyboard file in my application and have 2 language supports, I create

> 'Localizable Strings'

for both languages and have one .storyboard file in

> Base.lproj  [image]

During log in user should change language , so I need to change language at runtime... Is it possible to do withour restarting application?

here is my code, but is doesn't work :) , cause 'bundle' is not loaded

```
var bundle = NSBundle.FromPath (NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource ("ru", "lproj"));
            bundle.Load ();
            var st = NSStoryboard.FromName ("Main", bundle);
            NSViewController contentVC = st?.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier (NSConstants.MainSplitViewControllerID) as NSViewController;
            NSApplication.SharedApplication.Windows.FirstOrDefault ().ContentViewController = contentVC;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ru", ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
```